# Chrome extension popup closed after requesting permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am calling this API from a Chrome extension I'm developing inside of a **popup** context:

```js
chrome.permissions.request({
  origins: [`https://google.com/`]
}, console.log)
```

However, whenever Chrome asks the user via their native alert to allow or deny permissions, my extension popup is closed after Google's alert dismisses, so I cannot finish the signup flow.

If the user has already provided permission for this domain, the user isn't prompted, I get `console.log(true)` and my popup window **does not** close.

What am I doing wrong, and if nothing, is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try requesting the permission from a background page.

Comment: Thanks @IvánNokonoko, I tried sending a message to request permissions to the background script and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: Well, this is how it is. You can create a new window via chrome.windows.create with your html that loads js that asks the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

[I made an issue in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1131592#c4), and their team is aware of the issue, at least. Hopefully will see released at some point!

My temporary fix is just to make `*://*/` a required permission instead of optional. Then I don't need to request permissions from the user at runtime. Which tells the user "this extension can access all websites", but at least the UX isn't terrible.